# Google Sheets: How Do I Return Row Value Associated With Second Most Recent Date in "Date" Column?

Tags: date, google-sheets, conditional-statements, formula

Let's say I have the following table below.  I'm looking for a Google Sheets formula that would return the value associated with the **second most recent date**.

So I would want to see the value 41 returned by a cell formula (associated with 1/15/2022 date).

[image: 1/1/2022 52 1/8/2022 53 1/15/2022 41 1/22/2022 37]

What is the formula to do this?

**Edit: The formula would need to work if I had a third or fourth columns as well --> columns C and D.  So what is the value in column C associated with the second most recent date in column A...**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*You may try:*

```js
=vlookup(large(A:A,2),A:B,2,)
```

[image]

Comment: thanks!  this works for two columns but what if I have a third column C and I want to pull the value in col C associated with the second most recent date in A?  

I tried your formula in the above case and it doesn't appear to work ...

Comment: maybe try the *xlookup* its straightforward `=xlookup(large(A:A,2),A:A,C:C)` If you wish to pull both B and C then use `=xlookup(large(A:A,2),A:A,B:C)` OR another alternative would be `=filter(B:C,A:A=large(A:A,2))`

Comment: Your "=filter(B:C,A:A=large(A:A,2))" worked!  Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 1):

I would think this would work for you (replace B2:B with C2:C for the same value in column C)

`=INDEX(SORTN(B2:B,2,0,A2:A,0),2)`